# git svn wont rebase anymore after svn repo renaming

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I recently renamed my svn repository with which I was working via git-svn. I thought if I rename the folder in which my git project is living and update the git config where it says `url = svn://foo/bar` to the new name it would just work, but instead I get following error:

`Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`

What is left to do, to get it working again??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name of the SVN repository is part of the `git svn id` (and thus part of the commit hashes), so you cannot just rename your svn remote.

The easiest solution for this problem, is to do another clone of your svn repository, and replay any changes not committed to the old repo:

```
/tmp/oldclone$ git format-patch origin/trunk
/tmp/oldclone$ cd /tmp
/tmp$ git svn clone svn:/new.remote/ newclone
/tmp$ cd newclone
/tmp/newclone$ git am /tmp/oldclone/????-*.patch
/tmp/newclone$ git svn dcommit
```

as for tracking `svn rename` of directories within a single SVN repository, you can use the `--trunk` option to acchieve that.
Assuming you had originally a directory `/project1/` in the *root* of your repository, and you renamed it `/projectA/` (using something like `svn mv project1 projectA`), you can do a partial checkout of the repository containing the full history with something like:

```
/tmp$ git svn clone --trunk=/ svn:/new.remote/ newclone
```

Comment: Both git and svn repos are up to date. I could do another clone, yes, but how can I preserve the complete history? If I just clone the new one with `git svn clone svn:/foo/bar`, the command `git log` will only show me the last commit...

Comment: so you haven't renamed the repository, but just a directory within the repository, and told git to do a partial checkout of your repo. This is not exactly what you asked for in the first place. anyhow, i updated the answer...

Comment: Your last line of code works like a charm, thank you!